# Best way to modify a variable by a list of objects in C#

Tags: c#, list, variables, object

I am trying to build an upgrade system for a project in unity with C# and was wondering what might be the best way to modify a variable, by an array of custom objects (size may vary) that have information of how much should the variable be changed.

some ideas pop to mind, but here are my concerns:

1. The first one is by using a property:

   ```
   public float SomeStat{
        get{
           float modStat = 0;

           foreach(StatChanger Stat in StatChangers){
              modStat += Stat.valueChange;
           }

           return modStat;
         }
   }
   ```

   this will solve my problem very cleanly, but my concern is that when the property is accessed, every frame for example, there will be a performance drop for a larger amount of items in the list
2. The second one is to call a function that updates the variable and stores it in another variable to be used every frame without a performance drop:

   ```
   public float someStat = 10;
   public float someStatModifed;

   void UpdateStat(){
        someStatModifed = someStat;

        foreach(StatChanger Stat in StatChangers){
           someStatModifed += Stat.valueChange;
        }
   }
   ```

   this works but I may forget to call it, and it becomes more messy when having more than one Variable that needs Changing.

should I use a combination of those two or is there better ways of doing it?

Comment: You should use `LazyLoad`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642331.aspx

Comment: If there is a performance issue ( and that requires profiling if the complete app) you could calc the sum in the constructor, and then tweek it each time a StatChanger changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't say what the performance would be, relative to anything else, but you can use LINQ:

```
someStatModifed += StatChangers.Sum(stat => stat.valueChange);
```

Also, don't worry too much about optimizing it until there's a problem.  Do *try* to break it, but don't fix it unless it's noticeable even with large data sets.